# Powershell Events

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, agsxmpp

How to get the content of the **$Event** in powershell

This is my code

```
Add-Type -Path "D:\agsXMPP.dll"

$xmpp = New-Object "agsXMPP.XmppClientConnection"
$xmpp.Username = "fbusername"
$xmpp.Password = "fbpassword"
$xmpp.Server = "chat.facebook.com"


Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $xmpp -EventName OnXmppConnectionStateChanged -Action {
    Write-Host $Event
}

$xmpp.Open();
```

this will only output **System.Management.Automation.PSEventArgs**

That $Event, i expect **XmppConnectionState**

Answer (score 2):

`$EventSubscriber` : Contains a PSEventSubscriber object representing the subscriber of the event.

`$Event` : Contains a PSEventArgs object. The value is the same object as the one returned by the CmdLet Get-Event. So you can try to use properties as `$Event.TimeGenerated`.

`$EventArgs` : Contains the object representing the arguments of the event, the one you find in the property `SourceArgs` returned by Get-Event.

`$Sender` : Contains the object which generates this event,  the one you find in the property `Sender` returned by Get-Event.

Perhaps you are looking for `$EventArgs` ? Don't forget to use `| get-member` to retrieve the contents of the different vars.